# Uploading and handling images in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, powerpoint

I have a custom form on a SharePoint list in which the user uploads an image and a caption.

There is a PowerPoint slide with a template where the image should then go and the caption below it. Ideally I want the uploaded image to be taken from the SharePoint list and automatically input to the PowerPoint slide with the caption. The slide should then be saved as an image file and uploaded to SharePoint picture library to enable it to be used in a picture library slideshow on the homepage.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this or any other ways in which this may be possible.

I have tried using a combination of JavaScript and html with no luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following code to upload pic to sharepoint by rest api and js

```
var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
var file = fileInput[0].files[0];
var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '*****'; //if the library in subsite, You have to remove the forward slash "/" before the document library relative url. 
proccessUploadUsingJQueryAjax(file, serverRelativeUrlToFolder);

function getFileBuffer(file) {
     var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = function (e) {
          deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
     }
     reader.onerror = function (e) {
          deferred.reject(e.target.error);
     }
     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
     return deferred.promise();
}
function addFileToFolderUsingJQueryAjax(fileName, arrayBuffer, serverRelativeUrlToFolder) {
       // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{1}')/files/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            }
        });
    }
function proccessUploadUsingJQueryAjax(file, serverRelativeUrlToFolder){
     var getFile = getFileBuffer(file);
     getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {
     // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
            var addFile = addFileToFolderUsingJQueryAjax("image.jpg", arrayBuffer, serverRelativeUrlToFolder);
            addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
                alert("File Uploaded");
            });
            addFile.fail(function (error) { alert("Error Add File: " + error.responseText); });
        });
     getFile.fail(function (error) { alert("Error Get File: " + error.responseText); });
}
```